# How to terminate http connection in libcurl .After after downloading a x MB from total of 50 MB ?

Tags: c, http, curl

i have problem in termination connection after downloading first 10 mb from 500 mb file , i am receiving a segmentation fault , while terminating connection 
Here used call back function to get the data from curl

Comment: Rather than terminating at some arbitrary pre-crash point why not fix the undefined behaviour you're encountering properly?

Comment: i Will only know the the point of max bytes of file to be downloaded after creating connection .So most of time its arbitrary point